# Minimal number of $2$-cycles to generate $S^n$

Tags: group-theory

Title says it. I know it can be done with $n-1$ $2$-cycles: $(1,2),(1,3),\cdots (1,n)$ since these can make the $n$ cycle $(1,2,\cdots,n),$ and from $(1,2)$ and that $n$-cycle $S^n$ can be generated. But I'm having some difficulty putting together a proof one cannot use fewer. I'm fairly sure this must be known... is a proof involved, is there a link to a proof? Thanks.

Comment: Think of your $2$-cycles as edges of a graph. You need $n-1$ edges to ensure the graph is connected.

Comment: In fact, this is an if and only if. If you think of transpositions as edges of a graph with vertex set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, then they generate $S_n$ if and only if the graph is connected. The proof is actually quite easy, by induction.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown If explained a bit, would accept as answer.

Comment: Try it! All you have to show, is that if you have $S_n$ sitting inside $S_{n+1}$ and throw in any transposition including the element $n+1$, then together with $S_n$ it generates $S_{n+1}$. (In fact, much more is true, since $S_n$ is actually maximal in $S_{n+1}$.) Once you have that, it follows immediately by induction.

Comment: @verret Already thought of that-- thanks. Yes, using first $n$ terms get $S^n$ via induction, thus the $n$-cycle, then one more transposition gives next $S^{n+1}.$